# How to autofill with every other cell incremented by one

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need a list like `1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3|`. I need it to go to 50 just like that, so 100 columns, but only goes to 50. When I type 1 and drag it will bring me 1-50 automatically, but I need it to show how I did it above, so in the end I get 100 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fill across a row:

```
=INT((COLUMNS($A:A)+1)/2)
```

To fill down a column:

```
=INT((ROWS($1:1)+1)/2)
```

Comment: Now what if I were using a seriel number? like H00-001 and I want the next to be the same, then the 2 after thhat to be H00-002?

Comment: You could use something like `="H00-0"&TEXT(INT((COLUMNS($A:A)+1)/2),"00")`.

Answer (score 0):

In *A1,* enter `1`

in *B1,* enter `1`

in *C1,* enter `=a1+1`

Select the bottom right corner of *C1,* and drag it to the right.